# JQuery code has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added a script to my website template and somehow it does not work.

I think this could be due to a JS conflict but when using firebug, I cannot see anything abnormal.

Here is the link:

[Link](http://citylandlord.co.uk)

My JS code is as follow

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
// Using jQuery Event API v1.3
  $('#quote_home').on('click', function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'a', 'click', 'quote_home'); });
$('#quote_landlord').on('click', function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'a', 'click', 'quote_landlord');});
$('#quote_lerg').on('click', function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'a', 'click', 'quote_lerg');});
 $('#quote_business').on('click', function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'a', 'click', 'quote_business');});
$('#quote_tenant').on('click', function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'a', 'click', 'quote_tenant');
});
$('#quote_holidayhome').on('click', function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'a', 'click', 'quote_holidayhome');
});
$('#quote_referencing').on('click', function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'a', 'click', 'quote_referencing');});
$('#quote_mortgages').on('click', function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'a', 'click', 'quote_mortgages');
});});
```

This code is used as part of Google Analytics in order to track events on the site.

Comment: What have you done to test? Have you debugged to make sure the code is being executed on click? Such as doing an alert or console.log to make sure it's even firing the click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change may help you.
Here i found a code using

```
$(document).ready(myFunction);
```

change it with

```
jQuery(document).ready(myFunction);
```

Comment: Hello Parth, I added jQuery instead of $ as there was a conflict with some other scripts added on the site.

Comment: Yes so for that you need to use jQuery instead of $ for other things.

Comment: I think you need to check. i found $(document).ready(myFunction);  in website. This have to change with jQuery as you added jQuery.noConflict().